# ESRI Search Widget activeSourceIndex Usage (ArcGIS JS v4.8)

Tags: feature-service, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to ArcGIS JS. I have read the docs but I am looking for some example of setting the default search service.  I am looking to use **all** services (featureLayer and esri geocoding services) but also care about the order of the results returned.

I suspect this is accomplished using the [activeSource](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#activeSource) parameter of the search widget. But have not been able to find an example of this implemented.

I have tried implementing like this..

```
var searchWidget = new Search({
    container: "searchDiv",
    view: view,
    allPlaceholder: "Places or Tyler Communities",
    activeSource: 0,
    sources: [{
        featureLayer: {
            url: "https://services5.arcgis.com/6gTxIFMxZdWxCrVQ/arcgis/rest/services/...",
            popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{customer} is  Tyler Connected Community!",
                overwriteActions: true
            }
        },
        activeSourceIndex: 1,
        searchFields: ["customer", "city", "state"],
        displayField: "customer",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields: ["*"],
        name: "Tyler Communities",
        placeholder: "example: city of birmingham",
        zoomScale: 500000
    }]
});
```

I have also tried implementing like...

```
searchWidget.activeSource = 0;
```

But both return this error...

> dojo.js:340 Uncaught TypeError: [accessor] cannot assign to read-only
>   property 'activeSource' of esri.widgets.Search.SearchViewModel

To help explain. In the image below the feature layer results are returned below the geocoded results.  I would like to have the feature results (Tyler Communities) first.

[image]

I also need this reversed in the dropdown selections too.  See image below.

[image]

...

**EDIT 1:**

It was suggested I could remove the default using [includeDefaultSources](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#includeDefaultSources), which pushes the featureLayer to the top of the search list.  Is it then possible to add back the locator as a source in the searchWidget sources array?

Something similar to...

```
var searchWidget = new Search({
    container: "searchDiv",
    view: view,
    activeSourceIndex: 1,
    allPlaceholder: "Places or Tyler Communities",
    includeDefaultSources: false,
    sources: [{
        featureLayer: {
            url: "https://services5.arcgis.com/6gTxIFMxZdWxCrVQ/arcgis/rest/services/customers_2/FeatureServer/0",
            //url: customersLayer,
            popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{customer} is  Tyler Connected Community!",
                overwriteActions: true
            }
        },
        searchFields: ["customer", "city", "state"],
        displayField: "customer",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields: ["*"],
        name: "Tyler Communities",
        placeholder: "example: city of birmingham",
        zoomScale: 500000
    }, {
    Locator: {
        url: "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer",
    },
      name: "World Geocoder",
    }]
});
```

**EDIT 2: Solved**

AS per @Katah, I was able to reorder the Search sources by first removing the default (ESRI World Geocoding) by assigning [includeDefaultSources](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#includeDefaultSources) to *false* and then adding it back manually at the bottom of the source list.  I could then assign [activeSourceIndex](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#activeSourceIndex) to -1 to use all from my source list in the proper order. Demonstrated below.

```
var searchWidget = new Search({
    container: "searchDiv",
    view: view,
    activeSourceIndex: -1,
    allPlaceholder: "Search Places or Features...",
    includeDefaultSources: false,
    locationEnabled: false,
    sources: [{
        featureLayer: {
            url: "https://services5.arcgis.com/6gTxIFMxZdWxCrVQ/arcgis/rest/services/customers_2/FeatureServer/0",
            //url: customersLayer,
            popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{customer} is Tyler Connected Community!",
                overwriteActions: true
            }
        },
        searchFields: ["customer", "city", "state"],
        ...
    }, {
        //Pass in the custom locator to the sources
        locator: new Locator({
            url: "http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer",
            popupTemplate: { overwriteActions: true },
        }),
        name: "World Geocoding",
        outFields: ["Match_addr"],
    }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the `includeDefaultSources` to `false`, if you do not need the default AGO Geolocator:

```
var searchWidget = new Search({
  container: "searchDiv",
  view: view,
  allPlaceholder: "Places or Tyler Communities",
  includeDefaultSources: false,
  sources: [{
    featureLayer: {
      url: "https://services5.arcgis.com/6gTxIFMxZdWxCrVQ/arcgis/rest/services/...",
      popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
        title: "{customer} is  Tyler Connected Community!",
        overwriteActions: true
      }
    },    
    searchFields: ["customer", "city", "state"],
    displayField: "customer",
    exactMatch: false,
    outFields: ["*"],
    name: "Tyler Communities",
    placeholder: "example: city of birmingham",
    zoomScale: 500000
  }]
});
```

That will remove the AGO Geolocator from the sources, and then only the sources that you have set up will be available.

Comment: Thanks @Katah.  This works well to push the featureLayer search to the top, but I still need the geocoder as the second search option.  See edits for what I am trying to do with your implementation.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for may late response. That was a great solution!